# What is the difference between conversion specifiers %i and %d in formatted IO functions (*printf / *scanf)

Tags: c++, c, printf, scanf, format-specifiers

What is the difference between `%d` and `%i` when used as format specifiers in `printf` and `scanf`?

Answer (score 331, accepted):

They are the same when used for output, e.g. with `printf`.

However, these are different when used as input specifier e.g. with `scanf`, where `%d` scans an integer as a signed decimal number, but `%i` defaults to decimal but also allows hexadecimal (if preceded by `0x`) and octal (if preceded by `0`).

So `033` would be 27 with `%i` but 33 with `%d`.

Comment: Expecting an int with possible zero-padding in sscanf seems to me to be the most reasonable default behavior. If you're not expecting Octal, that could cause subtle bugs. So this suggests that %d is a good specifier to use when you have to choose one arbitrarily, unless you explicitly want to read octal and/or hex.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense! Now that I know what to look for, this can also be seen in the documentation for [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) and [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

Comment: The octal thing bit me once in Javascript. (some numeric value from the db was initially in string form with leading zeros). Man that was a bugger to track down.

Answer (score 75):

These are identical for `printf` but different for `scanf`. For `printf`, both `%d` and `%i` designate a signed decimal integer. For `scanf`, `%d` and `%i` also means a signed integer but `%i` inteprets the input as a hexadecimal number if preceded by `0x` and octal if preceded by `0` and otherwise interprets the input as decimal.

Answer (score 24):

There is no difference between the `%i` and `%d` format specifiers for `printf`. We can see this by going to the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function* which also covers `printf` with respect to format specifiers and it says in paragraph *8*:

> The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:

and includes the following bullet:

> ```
> d,i     The int argument is converted to signed decimal in the style
>         [−]dddd. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to
>         appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer
>         digits, it is expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is
>         1. The result of converting a zero value with a precision of zero is
>         no characters.
> ```

On the other hand for `scanf` there is a difference, `%d` assume base 10 while `%i` auto detects the base. We can see this by going to section `7.19.6.2` *The fscanf function* which covers `scanf` with respect to format specifier, in paragraph *12* it says:

> The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:

and includes the following:

> ```
> d     Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the
>       same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtol function with
>       the value 10 for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall
>       be a pointer to signed integer.
>
> i     Matches an optionally signed integer, whose format is the same as
>       expected for the subject sequence of the strtol function with the
>       value 0 for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall be a
>       pointer to signed integer.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any in `printf` - the two are synonyms.

Comment: There's a difference when used in `scanf()` format string as the accepted answer says.