# Why should I use "%d" instead "%i" as conversion specifier for integers in C?

Tags: c, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between format specifiers %i and %d in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf)

This question is motivated by the fact I use to see this preference in all the C code I've read.

Comment: @Aravindhanarvi I guess they want some quick reputation?  They need to add reputation to finding of duplicates.  This question is clearly a dup but no one voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

```
%d and %i
```

mean same in printf i.e. int;signed decimal notation
but in scanf

%d is for decimal integer,int * and %i is for integer;int * the integer may be in octal(leading 0) or hexadecimal(leading 0x).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, %d implies base-10 (d is for DECImal), and i is base-flexible (you can use modifiers to indicate octal or hex). So, you should use d if you don't want to think about it, and you always want base-10

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `d` conversion specifiers are equivalent for `fprintf` but they are different for `fscanf`.

Both `i` and `d` are present in all C standards (C89, C90, C11).

`d` is more common than `i` so I prefer to use `d` for `fprintf`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just read the scanf's man page and I have checked what you just typed.