# What's the difference between printf("%i") and printf("%d")

Tags: c, printf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between format specifiers %i and %d in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf)

I just checked the reference, it says both of them indicate signed integer. I thought there must be some difference

Comment: Probably a bit of history there; I wouldn't know.

Comment: there's the SO duplicate mentioned by @paulsm4.  as 
quoted from the C99 standard document, section 7.19.6.1:
"8. The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
d,i The int argument is converted to signed decimal in the style [−]dddd. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it is expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. The result of converting a zero value with a precision of zero is no characters."  in other words, they are treated the same.

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks for pointing out the related question, it helps

Comment: @yozloy - my pleasure.  My comment seemed to get deleted, so let me repeat it here:  `"%i" and "%d" are identical for printf but different for scanf`: [difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference.

From the C99 standard document, section 7.19.6.1:

> d, i
>
> The int argument is converted to signed decimal in the style [−]dddd.
>   The precision speciﬁes the minimum number of digits to appear; if the
>   value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it is
>   expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. The result of
>   converting a zero value with a precision of zero is no characters