# Adding +1 to a variable on click of a button adding the wrong number

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsinteger

I am very new to Objective-c and probably really easy to solve but couldnt find an answer anywhere....

I am trying to add +1 to a variable every time the user clicks on the button but instead of adding +1 it adds +4

```
- (IBAction)addNewSet:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%i",_sliderTag);
    _sliderTag += 1;
   NSLog(@"ADD NEW    %i",_sliderTag);
}
```

`_sliderTag` is already an `NSInteger`:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger* sliderTag;
```

The first `NSLog` prints `0` and the 2nd after the add is performed prints `4`.  Could anyone explain why?  It is meant to print `0` the first one, as the point of this variable is to be a counter for setting tags.

Comment: Because you declared sliderTag to be a pointer rather than an int.  Didn't even need to look at your property declaration to tell that.

Comment: As the others said in their answers, you are using a pointer to an `NSInteger`. `NSInteger` isn't a class (as it indicates) but a typedef to something very similar to int.

Comment: @HAS - It's not whether it's a class or not, it's whether it's a pointer or not.  When you increment a pointer in C you increment by the size of the element pointed to.  One should not use a pointer where an int is intended.

Comment: @HotLicks Your are right, but usually when you (as a beginner) see `NSSomething` you think "Oh it's a class so create a pointer as usual". That's what he did, I think. But in that case he doesn't want a pointer.

Comment: Even if it were an NSNumber (which *is* a class), you wouldn't increment it that way.  Any time you're incrementing a pointer you're treading on thin ice.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry, I talked about the `@property` declaration, not the incrementing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like `_sliderTag` is a pointer to a type whose size is 4 bytes. Adding 1 to a pointer increments it by the size of the type it points to. Here are two examples that illustrate the difference:

```
NSInteger foo = 0;
foo += 1;
NSLog(@"result: foo = %d", foo);    // result: foo = 1

NSInteger *bar = 0;                 // note the '*'
bar += 1;
NSLog(@"result: bar = %d", bar);    // result: bar = 4
```

Comment: It is because you declared it as a pointer, `NSInteger *`, remove the star. `sizeof(*_sliderTag)` happens to be 4 on your system and increasing the pointer by 1 results in an address of 4 being printed.

Comment: @JonathanThurft - sliderTag is *not* an NSInteger, it's a pointer to NSInteger.  Entirely different thing.  (And a difference you need to know before you go ANY farther programming in Objective-C.)

Answer (score 1):

first, make sure _sliderTag is an int or Integer or int and not Integer* or int*, second, dont print it with %i, but with %d

Comment: Why not print with %i? When you print they do the same, see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf

Comment: just something i used to so i wrote it to be sure its like on my computer