# What is the difference between %i and %d in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer, string-formatting, number-formatting

OK I was looking into number formatting and I found that you could use **%d** or **%i** to format an integer.  For example:

```
number = 8
print "your number is %i." % number
```

or

```
number = 8
print "your number is %d." % number
```

But what is the difference?  I mean i found something but it was total jibberish.  Anyone speak Mild-Code or English here?

Comment: Python uses the C conventions here, the same answer applies.

Comment: If you ever want to upgrade to python 3, I recommend getting into the habit of using parens around the print body, since print is a function in python 3.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't really understand that though.  I was looking a bit for more English lol

Comment: RTFM on format specifiers. They're the same. What part of "signed integer decimal" don't you understand?

Comment: @malcolmk181: sure, an english language explanation is added below.

Comment: not really a duplicate this is a question about python the one marked as identical is explicitly a c++ question. sometimes stack overflow is weird.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Python copied the C formatting instructions.

For *output*, `%i` and `%d` are the exact same thing, both in Python and in C.

The difference lies in what these do when you use them to parse *input*, in C by using the `scanf()` function. See [Difference between format specifiers %i and %d in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf).

Python doesn't have a `scanf` equivalent, but the Python string formatting operations retained the two options to remain compatible with C.

The new `str.format()` and `format()` [format specification mini-language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) dropped support for `i` and stuck with `d` only.

Comment: OK thanks, that's a bit easier to understand :)

Comment: The new format specification mini-language may have dropped `i`, but it added `n`, which is almost as the same as `i` except it's locale-aware number separator-wise.

Comment: @martineau: Which means it is *not* the same thing as `d`. `i` *is* the same as `d`.

Comment: @Martijn: Sorry, my mistake, I meant to say "`n` is almost the same as `d` except...".

Answer (score 3):

No difference.

And here's [the proof.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

The reason why there are two is that, %i is just an alternative to %d ,if you want to look at it at a high level (from python point of view).

Here's what python.org has to say about %i: `Signed integer decimal.`

And %d: `Signed integer decimal.`

%d stands for decimal and %i for integer.

but both are same, you can use both.

Comment: @malcolmk i have answered and reasoned why there are 2 choices

Comment: Seems reasonable, but we'll never know for sure since it would require the ability to read minds in the past...

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any, see the Python String Formatting Manual:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: There's gotta be a reason though right?

Comment: The string output formatting in Python is obviously inspired by C. Martijn Pieters pointed you in the right direction already: [Difference between format specifiers %i and %d in printf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf)