# Union as a Structure Variable in C

Tags: c, pointers, structure, unions

I have the following structures:

```
complex_attribute
generic_attribute
```

I defined a union of these two, like so:

```
union union_attribute{
    struct complex_attribute *complex;
    struct generic_attribute *generic;
};
```

And then i defined another structure which keeps track of the union and a code associated with it:

```
struct tagged_attribute{
    int code;
    union union_attribute *attribute;
};
```

Then, i defined another structure called Disk, which contains an array of pointers to tagger_attribute objects:

```
struct disk {
    struct tagged_attribute *attribute_ptr[100];
}
```

Now I am trying to access the code of the tagged attribute like this:

```
printf("%i", disk_ptr->attribute_ptr[counter]->code);
```

But I am getting a segmentation fault. Is my way of accessing the structure variable "code" incorrect?

Here is all of the relevant code from where I am trying to access "code":

```
struct disk* construct_disk(char* name, char* serial, char* vendor, char* model, int RPM, char *raid_type, int num_args, ...){
    struct disk *disk_ptr;
    disk_ptr = malloc (sizeof (struct disk));

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, num_args);
    int counter;
    int incrementer;
    //subattributes is a global variable
    incrementer = subattributes[counter];

    for(counter = 0; counter < num_attributes; counter++, incrementer = subattributes[counter]){
        printf("Counter = %i\n", counter);
        printf("incrementer = %i\n", incrementer);
        if (1){
            printf("Populating generic attribute");
            printf("%i", disk_ptr->attribute_ptr[counter]->code);
            //disk_ptr->attribute_ptr[counter]->code = GENERIC_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE;
            //disk_ptr->attribute_ptr[counter]->attribute->generic = construct_generic_attribute(va_arg(ap, int));
        }else{
            printf("Populating complex attribute");
            //struct generic_attribute* input_to_complex_attribute[incrementer];
            //int stepper;
            //for(stepper = 0; stepper<incrementer; stepper++){
            //  input_to_complex_attribute[stepper] = construct_generic_attribute(va_arg(ap, int));
            //}
            //disk_ptr->attribute_ptr[counter]->code = COMPLEX_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE;
            //disk_ptr->attribute_ptr[counter]->attribute->complex = construct_complex_attribute(5, incrementer, input_to_complex_attribute);
        }
    }

    va_end(ap);
    return disk_ptr;
}
```

Comment: Show **all** relevant code! Enable warnings. What do you get?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to c - how would I enable warnings?

Comment: If compiling on the command line with gcc or clang, use `-W -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic` for ANSI C99, and `-g` for debug info.

Comment: I would not call C99 "ANSI". Most associate the with the ANSI-only C89 (or the identical C90). However, you should post all relevantt code. How is `disk_ptr` declared, where defined? where/how are the structs allocated?

Comment: This is called a *smart union* . BTW there is no "%i" format for printf(). Use "%d" for decimal ints.

Comment: What is `num_attributes`?

Comment: num_attributes is a global variable - there is a lot of code, so I wanted to include only the relevant parts. Disk only accepts a certain number of complex or generic attributes and this number makes sure that disk does not get populated with more attributes than is allowed.

Comment: If you are new to C: please learn C before touching this stuff. You might underestimate the original author. Or his intentions.

Comment: @wildplasser actually %i is a valid format for printf and the same as %d for printf, the two behavior differently for scanf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf

Comment: Could be. But "%i" is not very current (could be obsolescent), So either the OP is resurracting old code, or using strange resources for education. It just doesn't fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't accessing `code` at all (which you should be using to check which union member is valid, of course).

You're accessing the `counter`th element of the `attribute_ptr` array, which is a pointer to a `tagged_attribute` and trying to dereference it (with `->`). Possibly without allocating that pointer (or any of the others in that array) first, nor initialising the memory after allocation (you haven't shown anything about that... failure to allocate correctly is a likely cause of your segfault.)

Of course, this assumes `disk_ptr` has been allocated and initialised correctly... which you haven't shown and may not have.

As already mentioned, show all relevant code if you want a more specific answer to your question. Further, compile with warnings enabled and learn to use tools such as `gdb` (GNU debugger) and `valgrind` (for memory issues) to debug your code.

EDIT: Now that you've added code, you have allocated `disk_ptr` but you never allocate anything in `attribute_ptr`, so it's just 100 pointers pointing to arbitrary places in memory.

Answer (score 1):

In C if a pointer is not pointing to valid memory you will have undefined behavior.  One of the common things that happens is a segmentation fault as the pointer has random chunk or was initialized to zero and when you try to access the memory it is pointing to the hardware detects that you are accessing an invalid memory page.  Every time you use `->` you are dereferencing the pointer and run the risk of a seg fault.  You should use a debugger to find the incorrect value.  An alternative is to print the values before you dereference them:

```
printf("disk_ptr = %p\n", disk_ptr);
printf("disk_ptr->attribute_ptr[counter] = %p\n", disk_ptr->attribute_ptr[counter]);
```

You should place this code before the print that you shows.  If `disk_ptr` is an invalid value the second print will fail.  The first print will always succeed but you should see if it is NULL or not.  If you do not see the second print that means the `disk_ptr` is an invalid pointer.  This because in the second print `disk_ptr` is dereferenced via the `->` operator and if it points to chunk it could (let me emphasize **could**) cause a seg fault (it could also overwrite some other data which might cause a seg fault later).  If the second print works but the print you shows does not then `disk_ptr->attribute_ptr[counter]` could be the invalid pointer.  Let me emphasize again because it is important.  If a pointer is not pointing to a correct memory location you have undefined behavior. Dereferencing that pointer could cause a seg fault right there or could modify memory in some way such that a seg fault occurs later.

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing `disk_ptr->attribute_ptr[1]`, but that array of pointers is not initialized (the pointers point nowhere).

You have to `malloc` the `struct tagged_attribute` entries for each pointer first.