# Use of %d type cast resulting in incorrect values output

Tags: c, casting, printf

in a recent program I have been writing I encountered a rather strange bug and after much research I haven't been able to figure out why it has happened. I am using printf to display a string followed by an integer to stdout. An idea of what this looks like would be:

```
printf("The number of characters on the screen is %d", &numberofchar);
```

The variable is declared as an integer and initialised as 1. After a loop the integer holds the correct value let's say 3 and in debugging I can confirm the variable is assigned this value in the printf statement.

However the output when read from stdout is a large random number such as 2530801.

I would like to understand why this happens and know if there is any alternative, for example would using `%i` stop this bug from occurring. I imagine its an error somehow in the stack but my knowledge of C is not too in depth.

Thank you for your help.

Note: this happens for all instances where `printf("%d", &int_variable)` is used to output an integer in my program. Value of all integers is always smaller than 20.

Comment: & exposes the memory address of the variable. It will be random because where the computer decides to put the variable in memory is random. Get rid of the & and it will work.

Comment: `%d` and the other **conversion-specifiers** in the format string of `printf`, `scanf` & friends are not casts! A cast is something completely different.

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled, the compiler with tell you about the type mismatch between the `%d` format and the actual argument `&int_variable` of type `int *`.  Use `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Answer (score 5):

> I imagine its [sic] an error somehow in the stack [...]

Yeah, sorta.

`printf` with the `%d` format specifier expects an **`int`**, **not** a pointer.
[Since `%i` is equivalent to `%d`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf), `%i` would be no improvement whatsoever.

Use

```
printf("%d", int_variable);
```

instead.

Comment: @Neijwiert I think the OP is aware of that; she/he just confused what to pass to `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

**&** is **address-of operator** here, it will give you the address of the variable. Just write the name of the variable inside **printf**

```
printf("%d", int_variable);
```

**%d** and **%i** both can be used for integer type variables

*Now for*

```
printf("The number of characters on the screen is %d", &numberofchar);
```

Assuming that **numberofchar** is an integer variable here, its value is undefined here with **& operator**. Use

```
printf("The number of characters on the screen is %d", numberofchar);
```

Comment: "it will print the address of numberofchar" Technically, it's undefined behavior, so it's not guaranteed to print anything at all.