# Which one is prefered %i or %d

Tags: c, printf

Just started learning c. And I noticed that there are 2 format specifiers for int.

```
%i
%d
```

I like to use `%i` (The i of **i**nteger). But I see most people use `%d`. Is there like a rule or something (like you have rules for variable naming (camelCase or underscores etc.)).

I allready noticed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/difference-between-format-specifiers-i-and-d-in-printf) but it did not really help.

But this is not my question. My question was which one is more commonly used. And which one should I pick. My question is not wat is the difference.
If you look good at these questions you see that in the other question there is nothing about which one is more commonly used they just say it is interchangeble.

Is it just so that you can choose. Is one of them more common to use or recommanded?

Comment: they're interchangeable, and both mean "signed (d)ecimal (i)nteger"

Comment: The linked question explains specifically what the differences are between them. How is having it explained again here going to be useful?

Comment: I wonder what is more commonly used in printf(), %i or %d?

Comment: @buratino: It would be (passingly) interesting to find out. Any ideas on how we might accomplish that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit how about a disgusting combination of `grep -o` and `wc` on the kernel?  I'm not going to do it, but someone else can :)

Comment: @user2864740 I was waiting for someone to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. Use whichever one you like. One stands for "integer" and the other stands for "decimal".

At a guess, there are two from early, conflicting implementations. And I'm talking like half a century ago.

I use `%d` and, to be honest, I haven't the faintest idea why.

They mean different things for `scanf`, though!

Comment: Only for `printf`.

Comment: @Quirk The question is tagged [tag:printf]. Might as well also say "only for programming languages" :D

Comment: I know it's tagged as such. But as long as I don't see it mentioned explicitly in the question, I think let's be pedantic. But you'd know better.

Comment: Oke I understand it. I already read the stuff about scanf so I understand that too. It is a bit confusing because in C# a decimal value is like a value with a lot of commas(larger then a double).

Comment: @TristanT: Yeah, best not to think about other languages when rationalising :) You'll find plenty of differences.

Comment: Isn't this left over FORTRAN 77 fun?

Comment: Given the fact that, as @Quirk observed, the two field specifiers have different meaning (than each other) to `scanf()`, I'd be inclined to guess that `printf()` supports both so that the same format strings can be used with both `scanf()` and `printf()`, without sacrificing either of the two distinct behaviors they provide to `scanf()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Maybe. Can't think of many scenarios in which output and input need to be identical though.