# Automatically run code again in C

Tags: c

I want the user to be able to immediately re-enter another value if the value originally entered is less than 0 or more than 23. Currently, my code outputs "please re-enter a value less than 24" and stops. It then has to be run again before the user can re-input another value.

```
{
    printf ("What is the height of the half-pyramids?\n");
        int height = get_int();
        if (height>23)
        {
            printf("please re-enter a value less than 24\n");
        }
        else if (height<0)
        {
            printf("please re-enter a value more than 0\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%i", height);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a `while(1)` loop. Break out of it when the user's input is valid.

Comment: sorry, do you mind giving a more detailed example? i'm very new to this

Comment: @noviceengineer13 What about reading a book covering the basics of the c language instead of asking here?

Comment: okay sorry my bad! guess you're right @user0042

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop.

```
while(1) {
    printf ("What is the height of the half-pyramids?\n");
    int height = get_int();
    if (height>23)
    {
        printf("please re-enter a value less than 24\n");
    }
    else if (height<0)
    {
        printf("please re-enter a value more than 0\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n", height);
        break; // stop stop looping
}
```

BTW, it's more idiomatic to use `%d` to print integers, not `%i`. See [What is the difference between conversion specifiers %i and %d in formatted IO functions (*printf / *scanf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893490/what-is-the-difference-between-conversion-specifiers-i-and-d-in-formatted-io-f)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a do-while loop:

```
do {
    printf ("What is the height of the half-pyramids?\n");
    int height = get_int();
    if (height > 23) {
        printf("please re-enter a value less than 24\n");
    } else if (height <= 0) {
        printf("please re-enter a value more than 0\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("%i", height);
    }
} while (height <= 0 || height > 23);
```